# ADB is not recognizing my tablet ("waiting for device")

Tags: java, android, configuration, android-emulator, adb

I have windows 7 64 bit and Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26. My tablet is view pad 7

When I connect it with my computer it shows

> usb debugging connected

But when I write `adb logcat`

it shows me

> - waiting for device -

When I connect my htc phone with the same computer and type

`adb logcat`

it shows me the log of my phone. Basically I think it something related to driver as the device is connecting properly but not showing me the logs.

I have also tried this with motodev and found same results.

Comment: just make sure USB debigging is enabled on device and device drivers are installed.cant think of any other reason.

Comment: how can i check either the device driver is installed as i think usb driver is enough because I have tried to connect my other device on the same port and things are working fine for me.. only issue with viewpad 7 where it shows on device that USB Debugging connected but not connect adb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings, development > enable usb debugging. If it's not there try REMOTE ADB. It's on the market for free, it works via WIFI.

Comment: I got my solution basically it was related to my tablet adb as it had to be installed.. But i thought it will work similarly as my htc phone.. so, now its working fine for me thanks alfa and amol for kind help..